# Packaged assets not available in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, packaging

My bundling looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/1d2a6055946d7327a50fd77bf47689d4) and I call the resources like [this](https://gyazo.com/b20f4e3f6317f1866188fa631a108346). All works well when run from Eclipse, though when exported as a runnable Jar. The program appears to not be able to reference the resources
**Question**
Why are my assets not accessible when packaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File doesn't work well with jars, because the file system isn't set up to see into jars. If you use URL's to address your resources you should be fine.

EDIT: adding example.

Assuming your linked address phrase is correct (since the code works in Eclipse, that seems likely), the following should get you a working URL.

```
URL url = MapLoader.class.getResource("assets/xml/maps.xml");
```

What you do next depends on the class and method where you use this as an argument. If you check the API for the class & method where you are using the File as an argument, chances are, there will be a similar method that uses a URL.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use URL's to address the resources?

Comment: Example added, assumes your linked code example works in Eclipse.